# Convergence in distribution of empirical CDF

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Without using the fact that the empirical cdf $F_{n}(x)$ converges to $F(x)$ under higher modes of convergence, I want to show that the empirical cdf converges to F(x) in distribution. In other words, I want to show that

$(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^{n}1_{\{X_{k} \leq x\}} \rightarrow F(x)$ in distribution as $n\rightarrow \infty$. So I want to show that the cdf of $F_{n}(x)$, which I will denote $G_{n}(x)$, converges to $\delta_{F(x)}$, which denotes the cdf of a random variable with a point mass at F(x).

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The limiting distribution is $1_{F(x)\leq t}$. We can ignore the discontinuity at $t = F(x)$. If $t < F(x)$, find $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $t-F(x)< -\varepsilon$. Then $P(\mathbb{F}_n(x) \leq t) \leq P(|\mathbb{F}_n(x) - F(x)| \geq \varepsilon)$. Use Chebyshev to get a useful bound. Now modify the argument to work out the case $t > F(x)$.

Comment: How does this hint involve the empirical distribution function's cdf, $G_{n}(x)$?

Comment: $G_n(t)=P(\mathbb{F}_n(x)\leq t)$ where $\mathbb{F}_n$ is the EDF